# How to enumerate dates between two dates in Moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/) dates:

```
var fromDate = moment(new Date('1/1/2014'));
var toDate   = moment(new Date('6/1/2014'));
```

Does moment provide a way to enumerate all of the dates between these two dates?

If not, is there any better solution other than to make a loop which increments the `fromDate` by 1 until it reaches the `toDate`?

**Edit: Adding date enumeration method and problem**

I've mocked up a method for enumerating the days between two dates, but I'm running into an issue.

```
  var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var dates = [];

    startDate = startDate.add(1, 'days');

    while(startDate.format('M/D/YYYY') !== endDate.format('M/D/YYYY')) {
      console.log(startDate.toDate());
      dates.push(startDate.toDate());
      startDate = startDate.add(1, 'days');
    }

    return dates;
  };
```

Take a look at the output when I run `enumerateDaysBetweenDates( moment(new Date('1/1/2014')), moment(new Date('1/5/2014'));`

```
Thu Jan 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
Fri Jan 03 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
Sat Jan 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
[ Sun Jan 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST),
  Sun Jan 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST),
  Sun Jan 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) ]
```

It's console.logging the right dates, but only the final date is being added to the array. How/why is this? This smells like some sort of variable reference issue - but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

[`.add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) is a mutator method, so the assignment in this line is unnecessary:

```
startDate = startDate.add(1, 'days');
```

You can just do this, and have the same effect:

```
startDate.add(1, 'days');
```

While it's name would imply the creation of a new `Date` object, the [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method really just returns the existing internal `Date` object.

So, none of your method calls are creating new `Date` or `moment` object instances.  Fix that by using [`.clone()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) to get a new instance:

```
startDate = startDate.clone().add(1, 'days');
```

Or better yet, wrap the values in a call to `moment()` as [Mtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334110/mtz) suggests in a comment, and it will clone the instance, if the value is a moment object, or it will parse the input to create a new moment instance.

```
startDate = moment(startDate).add(1, 'days');
```

I think a date enumerator method should not change either of the arguments passed in.  I'd create a separate variable for enumerating.  I'd also compare the dates directly, rather than comparing strings:

```
var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var dates = [];

    var currDate = moment(startDate).startOf('day');
    var lastDate = moment(endDate).startOf('day');

    while(currDate.add(1, 'days').diff(lastDate) < 0) {
        console.log(currDate.toDate());
        dates.push(currDate.clone().toDate());
    }

    return dates;
};
```

Comment: Didn't know about the clone method. Sweet! Thanks.

Comment: Note that `moment().add(period, number) is deprecated. Please use moment().add(number, period)`.

Comment: Interesting about the argument order switch. I guess they did that to make a chain of date manipulation functions read more like an English sentence, but if you wanted to use Moment together with a currying/partial application library you'd want `.add(period, number)`, wouldn't you?

Comment: Instead of classic while I used "do{ } while (condition)" to don't skip the first day

Comment: I would do `var currDate = moment(startDate).startOf('day')` and same for `lastDate` because then the input doesn't need to be a `moment` instance but can be anything `moment` can handle. It automatically creates a clone if it's already a `moment` instance so it's equivalent.

Comment: Thank you @Eugenio your solution fixed the first day issue!

Comment: @tinyCoder great! Note that `do{} while(condition)` in JS is the equivalent `do until(not condition)` of other languages

Comment: The `moment` solution is ingenious! I made a solution for enumerating days, weeks, months or years.

Comment: If you want to include the currDate and lastDate you could do `dates.push(currDate.toDate())` before your while loop and then do `dates.push(lastDate.toDate())` after the loop.

Answer (score 55):

Got it for you:

```
var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var now = startDate.clone(), dates = [];

    while (now.isSameOrBefore(endDate)) {
        dates.push(now.format('M/D/YYYY'));
        now.add(1, 'days');
    }
    return dates;
};
```

Referencing `now` rather than `startDate` made all the difference.

If you're not after an inclusive search then change `.isSameOrBefore` to `.isBefore`

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/sRE76/118/

Comment: had to swap `now.format('M/D/YYYY') <= endDate.format('M/D/YYYY')` for `now.isBefore(endDate)` to get this working in fiddle

Comment: @Mangopop Thanks, I've updated my answer to include better methods. I also added `|| now.isSame(endDate)` as the original answer was endDate inclusive.

Comment: Super. Also used spread on Set to use this on multiple date ranges and get a set of results without duplicates when date ranges overlap: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32000937/756177

Comment: You can use `now.isSameOrBefore(endDate)` instead of `now.isBefore(endDate) || now.isSame(endDate)` See [moment docs here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/)

Comment: @Sabin thanks for that. I've updated this answer to reflect the new methods.

Comment: Amazing! this was better then the other answer that was skipping the first day.

Comment: Or use `now.clone()` instead of `now.format('M/D/YYYY')` to get the actual Moment instances.

Answer (score 16):

use moment and work with while loop, code will run in loop untill startDate is equal to endDate and push startDate and then increment it with 1 day so can get next date

```
function enumerateDaysBetweenDates (startDate, endDate){
  let date = []
  while(moment(startDate) <= moment(endDate)){
    date.push(startDate);
    startDate = moment(startDate).add(1, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  }
  return date;
}
```

you can test it by calling function like this

```
let dateArr = enumerateDaysBetweenDates('2019-01-01', '2019-01-10');
```

Comment: If startDate == endDate and i i need the array as ['2020-06-21','2020-06-21'], how to rewrite this code?

Comment: I think you have to clone the date before operating on them or it will mutate them all around the code.
`let clonedStartDate = startDate.clone();` and `const clonedEndDate = endDate.clone();`

Comment: if someone is facing a problem where the first date in the array isn't the same as the other dates just change `date.push(startDate);` to                       `date.push(moment(startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));`

Answer (score 9):

Using `moment library` and `for loop` you can enumerate between two dates.

```js
let startDate = moment('2020-06-21');
let endDate = moment('2020-07-15');
let date = [];

for (var m = moment(startDate); m.isBefore(endDate); m.add(1, 'days')) {
    date.push(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If startDate == endDate and i i need the array as ['2020-06-21','2020-06-21'], how to rewrite this code ? @Tyagi

Comment: just change the line to: `for (var m = moment(startDate); m.isSameOrBefore(endDate); m.add(1, 'days'))`

Comment: Just note that the ```isSameOrBefore``` and ```isSameOrAfter``` methods were introduced since version 2.11.0 of moment

Comment: thank god. you saved my life. thanks tyagi bhai

Answer (score 5):

Momentjs doesn't provide this by itself but there is a plugin which offers it: [`moment-range`](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range).

Specifically, check out the [Iteration docs](https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range#iteration).

Comment: now they do provide check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64330459/12674966

Answer (score 3):

As an extension of Kyle's answer - I've been trying to get this to work with Unix timestamps and after lots of trial and error I got it to work and thought I'd post it here in case anyone is seeking the same thing and needs it. See my code below:

```
fromDate = moment.unix(req.params.dateFrom).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
toDate = moment.unix(req.params.dateTo).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

// Returns an array of dates between the two dates
function enumerateDaysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) {
    startDate = moment(startDate);
    endDate = moment(endDate);

    var now = startDate, dates = [];

    while (now.isBefore(endDate) || now.isSame(endDate)) {
        dates.push(now.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        now.add(1, 'days');
    }
    return dates;
};
```

Note that I convert it to Unix, then convert that value to moment again. This was the issue that I had, you need to make it a moment value again in order for this to work.

Example usage:

```
fromDate = '2017/03/11' // AFTER conversion from Unix
toDate = '2017/03/13' // AFTER conversion from Unix

console.log(enumerateDaysBetweenDates(fromDate, toDate));
```

Will return:

```
['2017/03/11', '2017/03/12', '2017/03/13']
```

Answer (score 3):

Using ES6 notation

```js
const from = moment('01/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
const to   = moment('06/01/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY')

const nbDays = to.diff(from, 'days') + 1
const result = [...Array(nbDays).keys()]
          .map(i => from.clone().add(i, 'd'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily enumerate with `moment.js` Here is a more generic solution for days, weeks, months or years:

https://gist.github.com/gvko/76f0d7b4b61b18fabfe9c0cc24fc3d2a

Comment: @AdarshMadrecha Page not found.

Answer (score 0):

> Using moment library and for loop you can enumerate between two dates.

```js
const moment = require('moment');

 let startDate = moment('2021-12-24');
 let endDate = moment('2022-1-4');
 let date = [];

 for (var m = moment(startDate); m.isSameOrBefore(endDate); m.add(1, 'days')) {
      date.push(m.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
  }

 console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

A short solution using recursion

```
import type { Moment } from 'moment';

export const getDatesBetween = (start: Moment, end: Moment): Moment[] => {
  if (!start.isValid() || !end.isValid() || start.isAfter(end, 'day')) return [];

  if (start.isSame(end, 'day')) return [start];

  return [start].concat(getDatesBetween(start.clone().add(1, 'day'), end));
};
```