# Merge data from an object into existing Map()?

Tags: javascript

How do we merge data from an object to an existing `Map`?

To create a `Map` from an object we can use this:

```js
const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(myObject));
```

Is there a way to do the same to an existing Map() without using `for` loop?

```js
const myObject = {
  test: "blah",
  ok: 123
}

const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(myObject));

const mySecondObject = {
  test: "new value",
  foo: "bar"
}

for(let i in mySecondObject)
{
  myMap.set(i, mySecondObject[i]);
}

console.log({size: myMap.size, test: myMap.get("test"), myMap});
```

Comment: Why are trying to avoid `for` loops? Of course you can use some method that does it internally (e.g. `forEach` or `reduce`), but no, you can obviously not avoid the iteration

Comment: Only thing I can think of is creating a new map from the concatenated entries of the current map and object but seems like even more work than just looping

Comment: Just wondering if there is another method available. Like with objects we can simply use `Object.assign()` method, so I was wondering if Maps have something similar too.

Comment: @vanowm there is no such method to set many values at once. The reference is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Related: [Simplest way to merge ES6 Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32000865/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

Note: the console in stackoverflow prevents Maps from being printed properly. It will work if you paste the code elsewhere.

If the objective is concise code, you can do this:

```js
const myObject = {
  test: "blah",
  ok: 123
}

const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(myObject));

const mySecondObject = {
  test: "new value",
  foo: "bar"
}

Object.entries(mySecondObject).forEach(x => myMap.set(...x))

console.log({size: myMap.size, test: myMap.get("test"), myMap});
```

If you don't mind creating a new merged map, you can do so like this:

```js
const myObject = {
  test: "blah",
  ok: 123
}

const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(myObject));

const mySecondObject = {
  test: "new value",
  foo: "bar"
}

const mergedMap = new Map([...myMap, ...Object.entries(mySecondObject)])

console.log({size: mergedMap.size, test: mergedMap.get("test"), mergedMap});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `Map.prototype.merge` method from the [*collection methods* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-collection-methods), which is still in stage 1. With a polyfill, you could write

```
myMap.merge(Object.entries(mySecondObject));
```

But currently no such method exists. There are many ways to have a helper method do the enumeration of the object keys and/or iterate over them, which would allow you to avoid  `for` syntax, but they're not as straightforward:

```
for (const p in obj) map.set(p, obj[p]);
Object.keys(obj).forEach(p => map.set(p, obj[p]));
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => map.set(k, v));
Object.entries(obj).forEach(map.set.apply.bind(map.set, map))
```