# Get all the dates between two dates in fullcalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How to get all the dates between dates in fullCalendar plugin. for example, I selected start date as 29-03-2017 and my end date is 31-03-2017. I need all the dates in between this start date and end date, and then I want to push into an array. this is my sample code for fullcalendar.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
    select: function(start, end, date, jsEvent, view) {
       $('#sDate').text(moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
       $('#eDate').text(moment(end).format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795522/how-to-enumerate-dates-between-two-dates-in-moment . This is not really directly related to fullCalendar - you don't need any fullCalendar functionality to solve the problem, you just need momentJS + an array.

Comment: thank you @ADyson very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enumerate dates between two dates in Moment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795522/how-to-enumerate-dates-between-two-dates-in-moment)